# Custom names when for FromUrl formatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Before anything, let's look at this example code

```
public class SomeRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("_desc")]
    public string Description {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("_index")]
    public int StartIndex {get;set;}
}
.
.
.
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] SomeRequest request)
{
...
}
```

Alright so on POST methods, the SomeRequest is perfectly deserialized and I used custom names (_index and _desc) which by the way are not good names but I just wanted to make my point. When using GET method, though, the full name of the property have to be used in uri because the formatter for FromUri is used while for POST method JsonFormatter is used. So I'm just looking for a way to use custom names for this formatter just like the way I did for Json in POST method.

Thanks,
Peyman MO

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UrlDecode` and the `UrlEncodeUnicode` methods of the `HttpUtility` class. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx).